# PostgreSQL - How to handle invalid values when casting to timestamp in SELECT from jsonb data

Tags: postgresql, casting, timestamp, jsonb

I am trying to get data from a jsonb column and need to cast an attribute from the payload to timestamp.  But the query aborts when the value is null or invalid.

This is my select statement.

```
Select
    (jsonb_path_query(AnchorNode, '$.TestDate')#>> '{}')::timestamp as TestDate
From (
      Select 
          jsonb_path_query_first(payload, '$.node1[*].node2[*]') as AnchorNode
      From TestTable
     ) subq1
```

The invalid values could be only the Date or null.

How can I change the query to handle this.  There are about 7 or 8 date fields where I would need to do this

Thank you

Comment: That is tough. You could clean up your data or use a regular expression to check if the value has a certain format.

Comment: I am going to try `CASE` or `COALESCE` and see if that works.  Will post here once I try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible to achieve above using CASE statement.  It may also be done using COALESCE

```
Select
    case 
        when jsonb_typeof(AnchorNode -> 'TestDate') is null then null
        when jsonb_typeof(AnchorNode -> 'TestDate') = 'string' then (AnchorNode ->> 'TestDate')::timestamp
    end TestDateTS,
From (
      Select 
          jsonb_path_query_first(payload, '$.node1[*].node2[*]') as AnchorNode
      From TestTable
) subq1
```

OR

```
COALESCE((AnchorNode ->> 'TestDate')::timestamp, null)  as "TestDate"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybie try to cast text inside a function and return null on exception

```
create or replace function str_to_timestamp(_date text) returns timestamp
language plpgsql AS
$$
    BEGIN
        return _date::timestamp;

        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            return null::timestamp;
    END;
$$;
```